# Typo3 extension to search on zotero groups

Tags: search, typo3

I would like to have a typo3 extension to search at the same time content both on my web page and on external bibliographies in zotero groups.
There is something like this? Would be difficult to develop something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the extension "ke_search". It allows to write a "custom indexer" wich can contain PHP code to retrieve data from any API. I don't know if Zotero offers APIs but this would be one possible way to do it.

Comment: There's a [page for developers](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/start) and probably the [link to the web-API](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/web_api/v3/start) would be the right base to proceed.

Comment: Ke search is a good idea, but my typo3 version (8.7)doesn't allow me to use it

Comment: Yes it does up to version 2.8.1 / stable